# How to get started with Tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am pretty new to Tensorflow, and I am currently learning it through given website https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/get_started

It is said in the manual that:

> We've created a model, but we don't know how good it is yet. To evaluate the model on training data, we need a y placeholder to provide the desired values, and we need to write a loss function.
>
> A loss function measures how far apart the current model is from the provided data. We'll use a standard loss model for linear regression, which sums the squares of the deltas between the current model and the provided data. linear_model - y creates a vector where each element is the corresponding example's error delta. We call tf.square to square that error. Then, we sum all the squared errors to create a single scalar that abstracts the error of all examples using tf.reduce_sum:"

- q1."we don't know how good it is yet.", I didn't understand this
  quote as the simple model created is a simple slope equation and on
  what it should train for?, as the model is a simple slope. Is it
  require an perfect slope or what? why am I training that model and
  for what?
- q2.what is a loss function? Is loss function is used to determine the
  accuracy of the model? Why is it required?
- q3. I didn't understand " 'sums the squares of the deltas' between
  the current model and the provided data."
- q4.I didn't understood this part of code,"`squared_deltas =
  tf.square(linear_model - y)`

this is the code:

```py
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
squared_deltas = tf.square(linear_model - y)
loss = tf.reduce_sum(squared_deltas)
print(sess.run(loss, {x:[1,2,3,4], y:[0,-1,-2,-3]}))
```

this may be simple questions, but I am a beginner to Tensorflow and having a hard time understanding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) So you're kind of right about "Why should we train for a simple problem" but this is just an introduction piece. With any machine learning task you need to evaluate your model to see how good it is. In this case you are just trying to train to find the coefficients for the line of best fit.

2) A loss function in any machine learning context represents your error with your model. This usually means a function of your "distance" of your calculated value to the ground truth value. Think of it as an internal evaluation score. You want to minimise your loss so the gradients and parameter changes are based on your loss.

3/4) Your question here is more to do with least square regression. It's a statistical method to create lines of best fit between points. The deltas represent the differences between your calculated values and the truth values. The aim is to minimise the area of the squares and hence minise the error and have a better line of best fit.

[image: Least Squares Regression]

What you are doing in this Tensorflow example is creating a machine learning model that will learn the coefficients for the line of best fit automatically using a least squares based system.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much all of your question have to-do with the loss function.

The loss function is a function that determines how far apart your output are from the expected (correct) output.

It has two usages:

- Help the algorithm determine if the tweaking of the weight is helping going in the good or bad direction
- Determinate the accuracy (~the number of time your system guesses the correct answer)

The loss function is the sum of the deltas witch is: the addition of the diff (delta) between the expected output and the actual output.

I think It's squared to magnifies the error the algorithm makes.